Improving BottomSheet Dismissal Behavior on Android with Opacity Handling
We are using th49:BottomSheet for our .net maui project (iOS and Android). On iOS, when the BottomSheet opens, the page opacity automatically changes to 0.3, and when dismissed, it reverts to 1. However, on Android, we have to manually set the opacity to 0.3 before showing the BottomSheet and reset it to 1 after dismissing.
This works fine when buttons are used to dismiss the BottomSheet, but a problem arises when the user dismisses it by sliding it away. To handle this, we added a Tap Gesture on the page Grid, but it’s not very effective.
Is there a better alternative to achieve this functionality?

I checked the documentation, and the BottomSheet provides three events: Show, Dismissed, and Showing. Currently, I am using these events in the ViewModel to manage the page opacity. However, if these events are handled in the code-behind file, it eliminates the need to manually set the page opacity every time. I’ve tested this approach, and it works perfectly.
For those who prefer not to use the code-behind file, an even better solution is to create a custom BottomSheet base class. This way, the event handling can be centralized, and individual BottomSheets can simply inherit the event properties from the base class. I’ve tested this approach as well, and it works seamlessly.
